# Where can I see my pull requests on GitHub?

Tags: github, pull-request

Is there a way to view on GitHub:

- All my pull requests
- My open pull requests

The only place where I usually see that is in my *Contribution Activity*, which unfortunately does not go further than 1 month ago.

Comment: This question would be better suited to the *Web Applications* Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

On the main homepage (not your userpage) there is a bar at the top with four buttons:

```
News Feed    Pull Requests    Issues    Stars
```

Click Pull Requests.

This home page can be accessed by clicking the octocat logo in the top-left, whereas your userpage is accessed by clicking your username in the top-right.

It should look like this:
[image]

Comment: Nice, thanks! I was so sure to find it in my user page that I didn't look elsewhere.

Comment: Yeah, I found this fact very confusing for the first few months of using github.

Comment: This has changed with issues / pull requests buttons being at the top right of every page now. Do you want to update your answer?

Answer (score 47):

I had the same question this morning and would have found hyperlinks easier than the accepted answer (which led me to write my own)!

- All my pull requests: These aren't (currently) shown on one page. But...
- My open pull requests: https://github.com/dashboard/pulls (open PRs are shown by default)
- My closed pull requests: https://github.com/dashboard/pulls?state=closed

### October 2014

[GitHub have launched new dashboards](https://github.com/blog/1901-managing-issues-and-pull-requests-across-repositories).

#### Example New URLs

- All my pull requests: https://github.com/pulls?q=is:pr+author:johnsyweb
- My open pull requests: https://github.com/pulls (your open PRs are still shown by default)
- My closed pull requests: https://github.com/pulls?q=is:pr+is:closed+author:johnsyweb

**Note:** Use your GitHub username rather than mine, which I've left in merely as an example.

Answer (score 25):

Visit [github.com/pulls](https://github.com/pulls) to see all your PRs.

Comment: This does not offer any information on top of NHDaly's and Johnsyweb's answers.

Comment: You end up in the same place, but you don't have to navigate through the UI, which is bound to change over time. Also, Johnsyweb's answer (with dashboard in the URL) redirects to the URL I've posted and GitHub might, at some point, break that old legacy URL.

Comment: Thank you @l1m5, your answer was indeed more useful to me than the other one because (as you expected) the UI has changed, and this URL brings me straight to where I wanted.

Comment: Thanks - @NHDaly 's answer is outdated with the new Github layout.

Comment: But doesn't this just show the open pull requests, not all pull requests (including ones that have already been merged)?

Answer (score 2):

(Just to add some snapshot snippets for visual benefits here, in addition to the already very well-documented responses previously / above)

## GitHub Main Page

On [GitHub Main Page](https://github.com/), there is a box on the right called "Repositories you contribute to" - I believe these are the repositories where user raised a pull-request and got merged.

[image: GitHub Main Page Contribution Box]

## GitHub Pull Page

... and more on [GitHub Pull Page](https://github.com/pulls):

Open:

[image: Open Pull Requests snapshot]

Closed:

[image: Closed Pull Requests snapshot]

Answer (score 0):

i used the pulse option in the right side panel https://github.com/{your username}/{your repo}/pulse

Answer (score 0):

To view the pull requests that your team is working on, you can use the Github "team" query like `team:myOrg/myTeamName`.  Or you can use [MyTeamsPRs](https://myteamsprs.com/) which lets you do the same but with an easier-to-use UI.

Answer (score 0):

Visit `github.com/{repoName}/pulls/{userName}` to view all your or your teammate's pull requests.

[image]